# if statement always return true even for simple integer values

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i facing issue my If statement returning always true, for each value.

```
 var radioValue = parseInt($("input[name=packageRadio]:checked").val())
            alert(radioValue); // 1000, 500, -1



            if ((radioValue) == -1);
            {
                alert("no");

            }
```

for every value `alert("no")` is always calling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove semicolon after if

```
if ((radioValue) == -1){
   alert("no");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolon `;` after `if`.And also remove braces `()` rounded around `radioValue`.
Like following

```
if (radioValue == -1){
   alert("no");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When JavaScript parsing, semicolon means the end of the statement (or line).
By that code you separate if statement and it's body.